# I wrote a loop that prints only the items in the list that begin with capital letter but islower() method doesnt return True if the item is lower case

Tags: python

```
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]
ignoredNames = []
i = 0

while i < len(friends):
    if friends[i].islower != True:
        print(friends[i])   
    else:
        ignoredNames.append(friends[i])
    i += 1

print(f"The Number Of The Ignored Names Is {len(ignoredNames)}")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to call the method as .islower() rather than .islower. The former calls the method and actually returns the boolean value you want in the check.

For instance:

```
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]
i=0
ignoredNames=[]
while i < len(friends):
    if friends[i].islower() != True:
        print(friends[i])   
    else:
        ignoredNames.append(friends[i])
    i += 1


print(ignoredNames)
```

Output:

```
Mohamed
Shady
Sherif
['ahmed', 'eman']
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate in python using `for ... in ...`.
Also you don't need to invert checking for `islower` if you want to check for the upper case of the first letter.
Also don't compare boolean values to boolean constants. It's redundant.

```py
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]
ignoredNames = []


for friend in friends:
    if friend[0].isupper():
        print(friend)   
    else:
        ignoredNames.append(friend)

print(f"The Number Of The Ignored Names Is {len(ignoredNames)}")
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I believe `friends[i].islower` is giving you the bound method rather than the result of that method. If you want the result, you should call `friends[i].islower()`:

```
friends = ["Mohamed", "Shady", "ahmed", "eman", "Sherif"]
ignoredNames = []
i = 0
while i < len(friends):
    if friends[i].islower() != True:
        print(friends[i])   
    else:
        ignoredNames.append(friends[i])
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
Mohamed
Shady
Sherif
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it